# OpenGL question - offtopic?

Tags: discussion, scope

[This question on where to start learning opengl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519/where-to-start-to-learn-opengl) was asked. I don't feel that there's any way that this could possibly be ontopic here. I realize that *nix systems use OpenGL instead of DirectX, but this isn't anything about a unix implementation this is asking for a howto on it.

I really do feel that it should be closed and moved to SO, or Game Development.

What's your take, should we allow stuff like this? At what point do we draw the line in the sand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenGL:

1. Is cross-platform. You can use it on Windows and other non-UNIX/Linux platforms
2. Is used primary in Game Development. Even if you use it for other things (like displaying Gnome-Shell ;) ) you will probably do it via toolkits.

I'd say game development. (On the other hand how to install OpenGL ;) )

Comment: yeah I wouldn't mind 'how to install opengl' or I'm having problems getting it working. or maybe even where would I go to get started on an opengl effect plugin for kwin. You know seeing as how things like kwin (or compiz) are specific to *nix atm. But nothing about this question even suggests *nix usage